# How to declare chess pieces in a chess game?

Tags: java

Im coding a chess game actually. I made the chessboard with cases and I can get coordinates.

My question is : How can I make (by example) a *Pawn* class with its attributes (*color* etc..) for my game.

Thanks everyone!

My code actually is :

```
    package coordboutons;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CoordBoutons extends JFrame {

CoordBoutons() {
    super("GridLayout");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contenant = getContentPane();
    contenant.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            contenant.add(new CaseEchiquier(i, j));
        }
    }

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

class CaseEchiquier extends JPanel {

    private int lin, col;
    private char column;

    CaseEchiquier(int i, int j) {
        lin = i;
        col = j;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 75));
        setBackground((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GRAY);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                CaseEchiquier current =(CaseEchiquier)e.getSource(); // get the object that the user pressed
                int linX = current.getLin();
                int colY = current.getCol();
                System.out.println(lin+"   "+col);

            }



        });

    }
    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getLin() {
        return lin;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            CoordBoutons coordBoutons = new CoordBoutons();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Classes and objects is basically what's object oriented programming is about. You already have created and instantiated some classes in your example. Creating a new `Pawn` class is just the same.

Comment: I would recommend reading about the java `enum`. It looks like a better option here than classes as they come from a limited set of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the way to go about this is first defining an abstract Piece class (which would define functions like `getColor()`, `getPosition()` and `setPosition(x,y)`, and require implementation of `getMovementOptions`, and so on). Then you can make six different classes that extend `Piece`: Pawn, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Queen, and King. Each of these can then implement `getMovementOptions` as appropriate.

The advantage of using a base class like this is that you can treat all the Pieces the same way when you're writing the code to actually play a game: you choose a `Piece p`, and move it to a legal square as defined by a call to `p.getMovementOptions()` (or however you end up defining this method; it probably needs access to the board position, for instance).

```
public abstract class Piece {
    public Color getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {
        this.color = c;
    }

    public Square getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Square p) {
        this.position = p;
    }

    public List<Square> getMovementOptions(Board b);
}

public class Pawn extends Piece {
    public List<Square> getMovementOptions(Board b) {
        // forward zero, one, or two squares, or capture diagonally one square ahead!
        // The list is based on this.position and the given Board.
    }
}
```

Comment: Color, Square, List<Square> are private attributes in the abstract Piece class that I need to declare ? Because they aren't in my code and I use 'lin' and 'col' to get coords. I'm pretty sure that it's obviously obvious, I'm starting Java but I want progress !!

Comment: @user2360545 There are various parts of this that I haven't defined for you, like `Color` and `Square`. The idea is that these would be classes that store color or location information. I just used these class names to make my example clear: you can implement them however you want. Maybe a color is just a String, and a position is just a pair of coordinates (or perhaps a String with an algebraic chess location like "e4"). `List` is a standard Java class that stores a list of objects (in my code, a list of `Square`s).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a class

```
public class ChessPiece
{
    Color color;
    ...
}
```

.

```
public class Pawn extends ChessPiece
{
    public Pawn(Color c)
    {
        this.color = c;
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd make the color a property of ChessPiece, since it's common to all of them.  Pawn would just be a "marker".  Or you could forgo subclassing entirely and just make "Pawn" a value in the "pieceType" field in ChessPiece.

Comment: Okay I think I understand but where I define the Color attribute ? How can I use my 'lin' and 'col' positions to move my Pawn piece ?